# Schedulers.immediate

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid

Может кто-нибудь объяснить предназначение данной функции? Не смог нагуглить более менее понятной информации. 
    Где-то прочитал, что данная функция говорит "продолжить в том же потоке, котором выполнялась прошлая задача", но не пойму какой в этом смысл, если итак все будет выполняться в потоке, котором выполнялась прошлая задача

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторые операторы могут сами изменять `Scheduler`. К примеру `delay()`, `interval()`, `timer()`, `skip()`, `take()`, `timeout()` и другие.
Пример:

```
Observable.just(1)
    .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe();
```

Может показаться, что выполнение операторов после `delay()` произойдет в `Main` потоке, т.к. мы не указывали конкретный `Scheduler` в `subscribeOn`. Но это не так. Оператор `delay()` сменит `Scheduler` на `Schedulers.computation()` и дальнейший код будет выполнен в `Сomputation` потоке.

Чтобы этого не происходило (если нам этого не нужно) и предлагается использовать `Schedulers.immediate()`, который передается третьим параметром в оператор `delay()`:

```
Observable.just(1)
    .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.immediate())
    .subscribe();
```

При этом, `Observable` понимает, что дальнейший код нужно выполнить на том же потоке, что и предыдущая задача, т.е. в нашем случае в `Main` потоке.